# TypeScript Visual Studio TS1219 Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release.

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I get the following error: `TS1219 Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.`

I know I can suppress this by setting `"experimentalDecorators": true` in `tsconfig.json`.

But I would still like to know why I get the error from this code:

```
import * as React from "react";

import scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader'

@scriptLoader(['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your-key'])
export default class Maps extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.map = null;
    }

    refs: {
        [string: string]: any;
        map: any;
    }
    map: any;

    componentWillReceiveProps({ isScriptLoaded, isScriptLoadSucceed }) {
        if (isScriptLoaded && !this.props.isScriptLoaded) { // load finished
            if (isScriptLoadSucceed) {
                this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
                    center: { lat: 10.794234, lng: 106.706541 },
                    zoom: 20
                });

                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                        const pos = {
                            lat: position.coords.latitude,
                            lng: position.coords.longitude
                        };

                        this.map.setCenter(pos);

                        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: pos,
                            map: this.map,
                            title: 'Hello World!'
                        });
                    }, () => {
                        console.log('navigator disabled');
                    });
                } else {
                    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                    console.log('navigator disabled');
                }
            }
            else this.props.onError()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div ref="map" style={{ height: '80%', width: '100%' }}></div>
                {!this.map && <div className="center-md">Loading...</div>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `@scriptLoader(['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your-key'])` above the class is a decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I would still like to know why I get the error from this code:

Because you are using a decorator in `@scriptLoader(['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your-key'])`.